# How to import a file_A from package Foo into file_X in package Bar, whereby file_A imports file_B also contained in the parent package Foo

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

So a file_A in package Foo imports file_B, also in Foo.

In Package Bar, there's a file_X, and in file_X I want to import file_A. I can import file_B just fine into file_X, and file_A can import file_B just fine when running file_A,  however, I cannot for the life of me import file_A into file_X, as it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PycharmProjects/Bar/file_X.py", line 1, in <module>
    import Foo.file_A
  File "PycharmProjects/Foo/file_A.py", line 1, in <module>
    import file_B
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'file_B'
```

Here an image displaying the structure of my files.

[image]

I thought a good solution might be to import the files file_A and file_B in the **init** file in its parent package. I thought that by doing this, python would now have access to both files, so not only could it import file_A, but also file_B within file_A from file_X. However, I get the exact same error.

There is a way around this, actually, but one that I greatly disdain, and that is to import file_B into A as Foo.file_B, instead of just File_B. This however greatly disrupts naming and workflow when working in the Foo Package itself.

If anyone can provide a better solution to what I consider to be a hack, I would be eternally grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute imports.

To get around the `Foo.file_B` use:

`from Foo import file_B`

You also should be able to use:

`import Foo.file_B as file_b`

Comment: Hello Markez. Do you mean use from Foo import file_B inside of file_A, if so, it would really just be the same thing, but formatted differently. In fact, it's only longer, as now you need to write 'from' as well. I tested that in the __init__ of Foo, and in file_X, but I only get the same error. Thank you for your answer though.